# Update page - Change image name follow video id Laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I want change image name follow the video id in Laravel project. How to solve this?

Here is codes of controller

```
$old_video = Video::find($id);

          //video thumbnail uploaded
          if ($request->hasFile('image_path') != '') {
            $video_themnull = $request->file('image_path');
            $video_themnull_name =  uniqid() . Str::random('10') . '.' . $video_themnull->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $video_themnull_resize = Image::make($video_themnull->getRealPath());
            $video_themnull_resize->resize(400, 200);

          if ($video_themnull->isValid()) {

              if (isset($old_video->image_path)) {
                  $files_old = $old_video->image_path;
                  if ( file_exists($files_old)) {
                      unlink($files_old);
                  }
              }

              $video_themnull_resize->save(public_path('video/themnull/' . $video_themnull_name));
              $image_path = 'public/video/themnull/' . $video_themnull_name;

          }
        }
```

Comment: add below code inside if ($video_themnull->isValid())  condition  $old_video->image_path = $image_path; $old_video->save();

Comment: Hi @Mahesh, this can change the image name follow the video id? this code need to replace or add at where?

Comment: after $image_path = 'public/video/themnull/' . $video_themnull_name;

Comment: Hi @Mahesh, thanks but the image name still create random one, I want the image name change follow the video id.

Comment: in your code $video_themnull_name =  uniqid() . Str::random('10') . '.' . $video_themnull->getClientOriginalExtension(); you created the name like random if you want to add video id you should add $old_video->id to your file name. $video_themnull_name =  $old_video->id. Str::random('10') . '.' . $video_themnull->getClientOriginalExtension();

Comment: Hi @Mahesh, thanks for help, the problem solve

Comment: Hi @Mahesh, I got other question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70090903/create-page-change-image-name-problem-laravel, can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code

```
$video_themnull_name = uniqid() . Str::random('10') . '.' . $video_themnull->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

you created the  random file name if you want to add video id with your file name then you should add $old_video->id to your file name creation. so please rewrite above code like below

```
$video_themnull_name = $old_video->id. Str::random('10') . '.' . $video_themnull->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

and add below code inside if ($video_themnull->isValid()) condition

```
old_video->image_path = $image_path; 
$old_video->save();
```