# Create page - change image name problem Laravel

Tags: laravel, image, file-upload, image-upload

this is under create page and want to change the image name follow video id in Laravel project. But when I upload and save the image at create page, save at database name become /tmp/phpRXDHFh, I want the image name save at database as public/video/themnull/video-id.png. How to solve this?

Here is codes of controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->validate([
        'video_path'   => 'nullable|mimes:mp4,avi,mpeg,ogx,oga,ogv,ogg,webm| max:25600',
        'user_id'      => 'required | integer',
        'category_id'  => 'required | integer',
        'video_section_id'  => 'required | string',
        'title'         => 'required | string',
        'post_date'    => 'nullable | date',
        'description'   => 'nullable | string',
        'youtube_link'  => 'nullable | string',
        'image_path'    => 'nullable | image |  mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif | max:2140',
    ]);


    if ($request->check_type == 1) {

        $data['type'] = 'link';
    }

    $data['post_date'] = $request->post_date ?? date('Y-m-d');

    if ($request->hasFile('video_path') != '') {

        $art_video = $request->file('video_path');
        $ad_video_name = uniqid('video_') . Str::random('10') . '.' . $art_video->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $created_id = 0;

        $video_image_path = $request->file('image_path');
        $video_image_name =  $art_video->id. '.' . $video_image_path->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $video_image_path_resize = Image::make($video_image_path->getRealPath());
         $video_image_path_resize->resize(400, 200);
        if ($video_image_path->isValid()) {

            $video_image_path_resize->save(public_path('video/themnull/' . $video_image_name));
            $video_image_path = 'public/video/themnull/' . $video_image_name;
            $data['image_path'] = $video_image_path;
        }

        if ($art_video->isValid()) {
            $fileName = $ad_video_name;
            $foldername = '/video';
            $name = $fileName;
            $video_path = $art_video->storeAs($foldername, $name, 'public');

            $data['youtube_link'] = null;
            $data['type'] = 'directly';
            $data['video_path'] = 'public/' . $video_path;
            $created_id = Video::create($data);
        }
    } else {
        $created_id = Video::create($data);
    }
    if ($request->filled('tag_name')) {
        if ($created_id) {
            $last_inserted_id = $created_id->id;
            foreach ($request->tag_name as $tag_name) {
                $data2 = ([
                    'video_id' => $last_inserted_id,
                    'tag_name' => $tag_name
                ]);
                $created_id = VideoTag::create($data2);
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        $this->successfullymessage('Video  Added successfully ');
        return redirect()->back();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->failmessage($e->getMessage());
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: got anyone can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$extension = $request->file('image_path')->getClientOriginalName();
$fileName = time().'-'.$art_video->id..'.'.$extension; // you can use time with name if not, then use only $art_video->id..'.'.$extension;.
       
// $file->move('video/thumbnail',$fileName); to store in public folder

//  If you want to keep files in storage folder, you can use following : -

Storage::disk('public')->put('video/thumbnail/'.$fileName,File::get($request->file('image_path')));

// Dont't forget to run 'php artisan storage:link'
// It will store into your storage folder and you can access it by Storage::url('file_path)
```

Comment: Hi, where I need to put or replace?

Comment: from where you're modifying your image name and store your image. 

`$video_image_path = $request->file('image_path');
$video_image_name =  $art_video->id. '.' . $video_image_path->getClientOriginalExtension();`

Put this instead of `$video_image_path` and `$video_image_name` on the top 

`$extension = $request->file('image_path')->getClientOriginalName();
$fileName = time().'-'.$art_video->id..'.'.$extension;`

Comment: May be you're trying to store your image here - `$video_image_path_resize->save(public_path('video/themnull/' . $video_image_name));`

So replace the following to there - `Storage::disk('public')->put('video/thumbnail/'.$fileName,File::get($request->file('image_path')));`

and check your storage file.

Comment: Hi, still same the image name store at database still /tmp/phpPfJm8Q

Comment: I need the image name store at database (image_path) like public/video/themnull/video-id.png

Comment: Because you're storing `$data` rather than modified data. That's why the system gets a temp name. Store `'video/thumbnail'."/".$fileName` to your database. like you can store `Video::create(['file_path' => 'video/thumbnail'."/".$fileName, 'foo' => 'bar', '...' => '...'])`.

Comment: So mean I need change the $data['youtube_link'] = null;
            $data['type'] = 'directly';
            $data['video_path'] = 'public/' . $video_path;
            $created_id = Video::create($data);

Comment: Hi Masudul, so how?